# how to implement JSON Web Token with DRF (Django rest framework) and mongoengine?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, mongoengine

I'm using django-rest-framework and mongoengine as the backend framework for my REST API's and Angular JS as the front end. How can implement JSON Web Token (JWT) authentication with a custom User document?. I have checked this link https://jpadilla.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/. 
But it supports only django-rest with Auth User model. How shud I proceed with this? Should I try implementing it using the python library https://pyjwt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html ?. All suggestions are welcome.
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to configure in your settings file that

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_custom_user_class
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

You could then go on to use Django Rest Framework's authentication classes:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    ...
}
```

Comment: What in case of sqlalchemy as the ORM i.e. instead of MyUser(models.Model): I have MyUser(Base):

Answer (score 0):

django framework works with Relational database to use mongodb for api use this instead [django-rest-framework-mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine)
here is a nice article from medium [building rest api with django and mongodb](https://medium.com/@vasjaforutube/django-mongodb-django-rest-framework-mongoengine-ee4eb5857b9a)

use this for jwt [djangorestframework-simplejwt-mongoengine](https://djangorestframework-simplejwt-mongoengine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#usage)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31910262)